# How to predict output word for KeyedVectors word2vec?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

A [`gensim.models.Word2Vec`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) class has method [`predict_output_word()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.predict_output_word). Now I use prelearned model but it was saved in class [`gensim.models.KeyedVectors`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html). Have a the class analogue method? Or how can I get instance of `gensim.models.Word2Vec` from gensim.models.KeyedVectors`?

I know about `most_similar()` but it something another.

Answer (score 0):

A `KeyedVectors` instance is only the words and vectors themselves, **not** the full model, including internal weights that were important for training (and the internal predictions made during training).

So, a `KeyedVectors` object lacks the state required to make predictions, and thus also the method. (Note also that method is relatively expensive to run, only works with negative-sampling models, and isn't given results that are weighted quite the same as the 'sparse' semi-predictions made internally during training. The point of word2Vec isn't really accurate neighbor predictions, but using attempts-at-such-predictions to bootstrap an arrangement of vectors that has other useful properties.)

If you're training the words yourself, you should save the full model if you need full-model functionality later.

There's no way to turn a `KeyedVectors` method, or mere set-of-word-vectors, into a full `Word2Vec` model.